# Can I rewrite this query to LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, in-memory-database

I have such query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.""CmsId"") ""CmsId"", c.""Id"", c.""Title"" 
 FROM ""Content"" AS c
 LEFT JOIN ""TagsContents"" AS tc ON c.""Id"" = tc.""ContentId""
 LEFT JOIN ""Tags"" AS t ON tc.""TagId"" = t.""Id""
 WHERE lower(c.""LanguageCode"") = @language AND 
 (({GetTitleFilters(phraseWords)}) OR ({GetTagFilters(phraseWords)}))
 LIMIT @resultsPerPage OFFSET @offsetValue
```

**GetTitleFilters()** and **GetTagFilters()** are returning where clauses as string based on words in user input

I execute query like this

```
  var results = await _context.Contents
     .FromSqlRaw(query, queryParams)
     .AsNoTracking()
     .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

So my problem is: I'm trying to write tests for this logic. But i'm getting this error:

```
Query root of type 'FromSqlQueryRootExpression' wasn't handled by provider code. This issue happens when using a provider specific method on a different provider where it is not supported.
```

I'm using in-memory db to store data for this test. Not sure options I have here, but
my idea is to rewrite this query to LINQ and then it should be available for tests (I want to execute query on SQL side).

Maybe you can suggest me something, maybe there's a way to execute FromSqlRaw in-memory db?

**EDIT** Missing filter functions

```
    private string GetTitleFilters(List<string> words)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            var index = words.IndexOf(word);
            result.Append($@"(strpos(lower(c.""Title""), @word{index}) > 0)");
            if (!words.Last().Equals(word))
            {
                result.Append(" AND ");
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

```
    private string GetTagFilters(List<string> words)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            var index = words.IndexOf(word);
            result.Append(@$"(lower(t.""Name"") = @word{index})");
            if (!words.Last().Equals(word))
            {
                result.Append(" OR ");
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Post the code of `GetTitleFilters` and `GetTagFilters`, because that will determine what the LINQ query will look like. Instead of using raw SQL construct the query dynamically. Every LINQ operator returns a new query, it doesn't modify an existing one. That means you can apply multiple `Where` calls one after the other to add the filters you need.

Comment: BTW `lower(c.""LanguageCode"") = @language` prevents the database from using any indexes on `LanguageCode`. If you want case-insensitive searching use a case-insensitive collation for that column

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Thanks for your tip, added missing code

Comment: Essentially you're doing a `LIKE '%word%` for every word on titles and `Name in (w1, w2, w3)` for tags. You can generate the `IN` clause easily in LINQ with `words.Contains(c.Name)`. This will get converted to `c.Name IN ('word1','word2',...)`

Comment: For tags you're right, but for title filter I need to have all words inside

Comment: `AND` is easy, just chain `WHERE` calls. That won't use indexing. The other option is to use MATCH in boolean mode with `'+word1 +word2 +word3...'`, a pattern similar to what you'd use in a search engine. I don't think EF Core allows this *but* you can use `FromSQL` with that as the base of the query

Comment: Hmm, sound good but there might be situtation  when given words are in different order

Comment: In [Boolean Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html) the `+` sign means the word must exist, it doesn't specify the order. As the docs show you can specify that some words can be near one another, or that some words should never appear

Answer (score 1):

In-memory DB does not support raw SQL queries, for obvious reasons: it's not an SQL provider.

You can write a normal LINQ query like this

```cs
var results = await _context.Contents
    .Where(c => (
         phraseWords.All(word => c.Title.Contains(word))
         ||
         phraseWords.Any(word => c.Tags.Any(t => t.Name == word))
       )
       && string.Equals(c.LanguageCode, language, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Skip(offsetValue)
    .Take(resultsPerPage)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Given that the `DISTINCT` is on `c.CmsId` it is unnecessary if you are querying `Contents` directly, as there are no joins.

You should probably rethink `GetTitleFilters` and `GetTagFilters` anyway as they are doing SQL injection.

The benefits of using `await` on an in-memory DB are not clear, I don't think it will give much performance benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
1) I'm using await in my class with logic which i'm trying to test

2) I'm missing part with DISTINCT ON in this query - is this achivable in linq?

3) Functions for filters are returning statements as strings i'm not sure if where clause can use them

Comment: Rather than thanking you can upvote and/or accept (by clicking the check mark)

Comment: Added few remarks

Comment: Added `DistinctBy`. I can't help on the stringifying if you don't show code. Testing using in-memory DB is probably not great: a lot of features are not supported. Better to just create a test Postgres DB.

Comment: @Groomer post the function code or at least the statements they generate. You *can't* use those functions in a `Where` and using `FromSql` removes many of the benefits EF would give you. If you search for words in fields you probably need to use full text search indexes and MATCH instead of `LIKE` too.

Comment: Added missing functions. DistinctBy is supported on sql side?

Comment: It seems like it only works for filter in memory :( `.DistinctBy(c => c.CmsId)' could not be translated.`

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT` anyway: the only reason you put it in was because of the joins, which should have been in an `EXISTS` subquery.

Comment: unfortunetly I need this, I got this Distinct On because CmsId is not unique

Comment: @Charlieface as Groomer lacked to do it, I give you the upvote you were eager for ;)